# UIStoryboardSegue Error with selectedIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift

I am having an issue with my swift 3 segue code. I have made sure everything is connected in the storyboard and have looked for similar issues with swift 3. These are the specific lines of code I am getting errors with:

```
meals[selectedIndexPath.row] = meal
```

and

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

the full segue code block is as follows:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Show Detail" {
        let mealDetailViewController = segue.destination as!
        MealViewController
        // Get the cell that generated this segue
        if let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedMealCell)!
            let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {
    }
}

@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as?
        MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
            // Update an existing meal.
            meals[selectedIndexPath.row] = meal
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            // Add a new meal
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: meals.count, section: 0)
            meals.append(meal)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned the exact error, I'll guess that
this:

`if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {`

should be:

`if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.last {`

By doing this you'll only fetch one indexPath from indexPaths array.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This helped. I also changed those 2 lines to `        meals [(selectedIndexPath as IndexPath).row] = meal
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)`